# How to get recyclerView getItemCount - position start from 2 instead of 0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to connect my recyclerview two different mutableArray and one textView.

It works correctly instead of override fun getItemCount() starts from position 0 instead of 2. All data comes from firestore and is called in MainActivity class

In position 0 i have own adapter for newList and it works correctly, in position 1 i have textview and it works correctly. In position 2 i want to start this flowerList but for somereason it miss 2 first items from my flowerList.

**So my question is how i can make my**

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
   return flowerList.size
}
```

**To start from position 2 instead of position 0**

Here is my full code for that adapter:

```
class MainAdapter(val flowerList: MutableList<Flowers>, val newsList: MutableList<News>, val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private val TYPE_NEWS_LAYOUT = 0
    private val TYPE_TITLE_LAYOUT = 1
    private val TYPE_FLOWERS_LAYOUT = 2

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, position: Int): ViewHolder {
        if (position == TYPE_NEWS_LAYOUT) {
            val newsFeed = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.main_horizontal_recycler, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(newsFeed)

        } else if (position == TYPE_TITLE_LAYOUT) {
            val textView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_main_text_recycler, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(textView)

        } else {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_main_bottom_recycler, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(view)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (position == 0) {
            holder.itemView.main_top_recycler_horizontal.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
            holder.itemView.main_top_recycler_horizontal.adapter = MainHorizontalAdapter(newsList)
        } else if (position == 1) {
            holder.middleTitle.text = "Text here"
        } else {
            val flower = flowerList[position]
            holder.flowerName.text = flower.flowername
            Glide.with(context).load(flower.mainimageurl).into(holder.flowerImage)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        if (position == 0) {
            return TYPE_NEWS_LAYOUT
        } else if (position == 1)
            return TYPE_TITLE_LAYOUT
        else
            return TYPE_FLOWERS_LAYOUT
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return flowerList.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val flowerName = view.flower_name
        val flowerImage = view.flower_image
        val middleTitle = view.main_recycler_title
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incrementing a counter is going to be a problem because onBindViewHolder gets called every time the view gets recycled. Instead, I think you want to change the line

FROM:
`val flower = flowerList[position]`

TO: 
`val flower = flowerList[position - 2] // subtracting two, to account for the first two positions, in the adapter, that are your News and Title views`

Comment: This is not working. It remove 2 last items from array with this code. Example: [1,2,3,4,5]. Before this it showed: [3,4,5]. And now it show: [1,2,3]

Comment: you also need to update `getItemCount` to:

`override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return flowerList.size + 2
}`

To also account for the two hard-coded News and Title views